# Why Tensorflow error: `failed to convert object of type <class 'dict'> to Tensor` happens and How can I solve it?

Tags: tensorflow, regression, python-3.7, tensorflow-estimator, feature-engineering

I am doing a task on traffic analysis and I am stymied with some error in my code. My data rows are like this:

`qurter | DOW (Day of week)| Hour | density | speed | label (predicted speed for another half an hour)`

The values are like this:

```
1, 6, 19, 23, 53.32, 45.23
```

Which means in some specific street during `1st` quarter of `19` o'clock on `Friday`, density of traffic is measured `23` and current speed is `53.32`. the predicted speed would be `45.23`.

The task is to predict the speed for another half an hour by predictors given above.

I am using this code to build a TensorFlow `DNNRegressor` for data:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv')
X = data.iloc[:,:5].values
y = data.iloc[:, 5].values
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)

X_train = pd.DataFrame(data=scaler.transform(X_train),columns =    ['quarter','DOW','hour','density','speed'])
X_test = pd.DataFrame(data=scaler.transform(X_test),columns = ['quarter','DOW','hour','density','speed'])

y_train = pd.DataFrame(data=y_train,columns = ['label'])
y_test = pd.DataFrame(data=y_test,columns = ['label'])

import tensorflow as tf

speed = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('speed')
hour = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('hour')
density = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('density')
quarter= tf.feature_column.numeric_column('quarter')
DOW = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('DOW')

feat_cols = [h_percentage, DOW, hour, density, speed]
input_func = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x=X_train,y=y_train ,batch_size=10,num_epochs=1000,shuffle=False)

model = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(hidden_units=[5,5,5],feature_columns=feat_cols)
model.train(input_fn=input_func,steps=25000)
predict_input_func = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
  x=X_test,
  batch_size=10,
  num_epochs=1,
  shuffle=False)

pred_gen = model.predict(predict_input_func)

predictions = list(pred_gen)
final_preds = []
for pred in predictions:
    final_preds.append(pred['predictions'])

from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

mean_squared_error(y_test,final_preds)**0.5
```

when I run this code, It throws an error with this ending:

`TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'dict'> to Tensor. Contents: {'label': <tf.Tensor 'fifo_queue_DequeueUpTo:6' shape=(?,) dtype=float64>}. Consider casting elements to a supported type.`

First of all what is the concept of error? I couldn't find source for reason of error to deal with it. And how can I modify code for solution?

secondly does it improve the model performance to use tensorflow `categorical_column_with_identity` instead of `numeric_columns` for DOW which indicates days of week?

I also want to know if it's useful to merge `quarter` and `hour` as a single column like `day time` (`quarter` is minutes in an hour which is going to be normalized between 0 and 1)?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the error? Or the line in the code where it gets raised? About the day of the week, I think I'd use a categorical feature instead of a numerical one, it's more of a "type of day" than a real-valued characteristic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First of all what is the concept of error? I couldn't find source for
>   reason of error to deal with it. And how can I modify code for
>   solution?

Let me first talk about the solution to the problem. You need to change parameter `y` in `pandas_input_fn` as follows.

```
input_func = tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x=X_train,y=y_train['label'],batch_size=10,num_epochs=1000,shuffle=False)
```

It seems that the parameters `y` in `pandas_input_fn` doesn't support `dataframe` type when you run to `model.train()`. `pandas_input_fn` parses every sample `y` to a form similar to `{columnname: value}` in this case, but `model.train()` can't recognize it. So you need to pass `series` type.

> secondly does it improve the model performance to use tensorflow
>   categorical_column_with_identity instead of numeric_columns for DOW
>   which indicates days of week?

This involves when we should choose `categorical` or choose `numeric` for feature engineering. A very simple rule is to choose `numeric` if there is a significant difference between big and small in the internal comparison of your feature. If the feature does not have bigger or smaller significance, you should choose `categorical`. So I tend to choose `categorical_column_with_identity` for feature `DOW`.

> I also want to know if it's useful to merge quarter and hour as a
>   single column like day time (quarter is minutes in an hour which is
>   going to be normalized between 0 and 1)?

Cross features may bring some benefits such as latitude and longitude features. I recommend you to use `tf.feature_column.crossed_column`([link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/crossed_column)) here. It returns a column for performing crosses of categorical features. You can also continue to retain features `quarter` and `hour` in model at the same time, .

Comment: Many thanks for perfect reply. I wonder if there is any good references or tutorials for feature engineering concepts. If you know, let me know.

Comment: @MasoudMasoumiMoghadam I generally pay attention to some blogs about feature engineering.  You can look at [`Machine Learning Mastery`](https://machinelearningmastery.com/discover-feature-engineering-how-to-engineer-features-and-how-to-get-good-at-it/) and [`Towards Data Science`](https://towardsdatascience.com/) on `medium`.

Answer (score -3):

A similar error occurred to me:

`Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.autograph.operators.special_values.Undefined'> to Tensor.`

It occurred in a `tf.function` when I tried to use a variable that I had not assigned before.

To debug this, you have to remove `tf.function` from the method ;-)